# Vertically centring elements of a CSS grid in tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to lay out a grid of checkboxes in CSS, using Tailwind CSS. The basic structure is this:

```
    <div class="grid sm:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      <div>
        <div>
        <label for="-exact"><input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact">-exact</label>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="-exact"><input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact">-exact</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="-exact"><input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact">-exact</label>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
```

So I have an outer div which is the grid, then a series of "content" divs. The first content is 2 lines high (2 checkboxes). The second is one line high (one checkbox).

My problem is that the checkbox in the second grid box is aligned to the *top* of the box, and I want it centred vertically. I've added background colours so I can see that the div spans the whole height of the previous grid box, but I can find no way of centring the checkbox in the containing div.

Can anyone tell me how to get the effect I want? And more so, can someone explain to me how the box model works in a way that explains *why* it's not doing what I want? Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this with Tailwind, for consistency, but raw CSS would be OK as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Align](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items) your items to the center by applying the class `items-center` to your grid (this method will align all your items and might affect your other child elements in an undesired manner later on when you add more elements to the grid).

```
<div class="grid gap-4 sm:grid-cols-3 items-center">
```

You can also apply either `grid` or `flex` to the parent's container, which you want to center vertically (using `items-center`):

```
<div class="flex items-center">
    <label for="-exact">
        <input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact"> -exact
    </label>
</div>

<-- or  -->

<div class="grid items-center">
    <label for="-exact">
        <input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact"> -exact
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if it exactly answers your question, but the reason the elements stick to the top-left side is that it's still displayed as a [block](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp). Changing the parent to a grid doesn't change the display type of child elements.

> A block-level element always starts on a new line, and the browsers automatically add some space (a margin) before and after the element.

Comment: Ah. If I just add `items-center` to the existing grid, the elements get centred but no longer fill their grid space. But if I make the div containing the `label` element *also* a grid, and add `items-center` to that instead of adding it to the outer grid, then that works. I guess the key thing is that there aren't just two types of display, "block" and "inline", but "grid" is a *third* type, with different behaviour. Is that correct?

Comment: In flex and grid, unless you set the width/height of your elements to 100%, their size will be the minimal size they can take in the container. If you add `items-center`, the elements will take the same surface but in a centered align. And yes, you have block, align, table, and many more sub-display that all act in a unique, mostly different way. You can read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp and here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display

Comment: Adding `items-center` doesn't change the surface the elements take. Changing the display from `block` to `flex` does.
You can see this effect by changing the display type and inspecting the elements using the developer tools, it can give you a better understanding of the way it works :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood your error, the second `div` element positions on the top of the whole grid element but you want it to be in the center. Check this snippet out if that's the issue: *(I have vertically centered the second grid column)*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Main grid element with 2 child divs-->
  <div class="grid grid-flow-col gap-4">
    <!--First child div with 2 sub child div displayed as columns-->

    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <div class="p-5 bg-yellow-300">
        <label for="-exact"><input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact">-exact</label>
      </div>
      <div class="p-5 bg-red-300">
        <label for="-exact"><input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact">-exact</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Second child with 1 div element, centered in its place-->
    <div class="p-5 bg-green-300 h-full flex items-center">
      <label for="-exact"><input type="checkbox" id="-exact" value="-exact">-exact</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Explanation:** To place elements in center (or change their position), you have to give it a `display name` *e.g. block, flex, grid etc*. Then there are couple ways you could go and center/position your element. The most efficient one would be to use the relevant styles related to the `display name`. For example:

- For `Flex` model, you'd use `justify-content: center` which in Tailwind would be `justify-center` classname to center an element vertically. And to horizontally center it, you'd use `align-items: center` which in Tailwind would be `items-center` classname.
- For `Grid` model, you'd use `place-items: center` which in Tailwind would be `place-items-center` classname to center an element vertically & horizontally.

These are a bit different for each display property. You can look that up on google if you don't know. Hope that helps.